# Using query to select multiple headers instead of columns

Tags: regex, google-sheets, filter, array-formulas, transpose

I'm able to dynamically select a 1-dimensional array using the header name instead of a column letter.

```
=query(A:J, "select "&substitute(address(1,match("Header2",A1:J1,0,4),"1","")&"")
```

Is it possible to do this with a 2-dimensional array? So instead of selecting B:C, I would select Header2 : Header3?

I've tried using a couple variations of concat operator without success.

```
=query(A:J, "select "&substitute(address(1,match("Header2",A1:J1,0,4),"1","")&" "&:&" "&substitute(address(1,match("Header3",A1:J1,0,4),"1","")&"")
```

If it is useful or presents a possible workaround, the columns in question will always stay adjacent to each other. Header1 next to Header2 next to Header3, etc. However, Header1 could be in any column.

Comment: Can you share a copy of the sheet you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

transpose, select headers, transpose back:

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A:J), "where Col1 matches 'Header2|Header3|Header4'"))
```

or:

```
=FILTER(A:J, REGEXMATCH(A1:J1, "Header2|Header3|Header4"))
```

or:

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,         MATCH("Header2", 1:1, ))&":"&
                ADDRESS(ROWS(A:A), MATCH("Header4", 1:1, ))))
```

Comment: All work. First two options are a little cleaner. Anyway with these solutions to select a range (Header2 : Header5), instead of each Header? Just thinking if one needs to select 15 columns it could get a bit lengthy.

Comment: @jhaff you could use `TEXTJOIN("|", 1, "Header"&SEQUENCE(15, 1, 2))`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a missing `)` at the end of the `match`.

Once fixed, you can expand your solution to add other headers like this:

```
=query(A:J, "select "
&substitute(address(1,match("Header2",A1:J1,0),4),"1","")&","
&substitute(address(1,match("Header3",A1:J1,0),4),"1","")&","
&substitute(address(1,match("Header4",A1:J1,0),4),"1","")&"
")
```

Comment: This works. Is there a way to select a range using this method? So instead of matching every header, match Header2 : Header 5?

Comment: Yes, you could do something like: `=query({indirect(substitute(address(1,match("Header1",A1:J1,0),4),"1","")&":"&substitute(address(1,match("Header2",A1:J1,0),4),"1",""))}, "select *",1)`